# How can I use a Liquid-generated JSON as a "_data" site.data object in Jekyll?

Tags: json, jekyll, liquid

Using Liquid, I am trying to build a JSON object (`skills.json`) containing data from all of my Jekyll posts.

When I place this file in my `_data` folder in my project root directory per https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/, trying to access the data via `site.data.skills` with the inspect filter or console log resolves to nothing.

[final output section of my Liquid json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wu8U.png)

When I instead place my `skills.json` file in the `/assets/js/` folder in my root, I do see that the properly populated JSON file is added to my `_site` folder as expected. Copying this NEW file into the root `_data` folder successfully populates to my page as intended, and I am able to access all the data with `site.data.skills.KEY`.

[json generated from assets folder at build time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5vMS.png)

Is there any way that I could specify that the generated `skills.json` in my `/assets/js/` folder be the source for my data call?

Alternatively, is there a way to generate the final data and automatically move it to the `_data` folder ahead of building the site? I am open to any suggestions for how to automate this. As a warning, I am pretty new to web development in general, so any references or links would be a tremendous help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this, I believe that the issue lies in how the site is built. The `skills.json` file gets generated on the first build, and then when it is added to the `_data` folder, the site gets built AGAIN to update everything that hits that data. With this iterative process, I don't know if it would be possible to both generate the new file and use it as a source to update everything dependent on the data in the same pass.

As far as automating goes, my thinking is that a Ruby plugin to compare the newly generated files against the `_data` folder and overwrite if the source is different/newer would be the way to go, but I'm still open to any suggestions!